# How to hide or remove default home tab in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

[image]

I want to Hide or remove default home tab in my sandbox org. if it is not possible then can i make my VF page as Default landing home page. How can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove the Home tab, but you can choose to make any tab of your choosing the default. Simply go to Setup > Create > Apps, create a new app (or edit an existing app), and set the Default Landing Tab. You'll automatically land on the Default Landing Page when you login and that was the last app you've used, or when you switch to that app. To make a Visualforce page available as a tab you can land on, create a new Visualforce tab in Setup > Create > Tabs before editing the App that you want to specify the Default Landing Page for.

Comment: is it possible to redirect users from the home tab to the vf tab of your choice?

Comment: @jaw999 You could create a VF page like: `<apex:page><script>window.top.location.href='{!URLFOR($Page.somePage,null,null)}'</script></apex:page>`, create a home page component for that page, and add the component to your home page layout. This would cause the user to be redirected to a location of your choice. They will briefly see the home tab but be directed to the page of your choice.

Comment: hmm, thanks, i am getting syntax error with my piece -  <script>window.top.location.href='{!URLFOR($Page.SaleshomeVF,null,null)‌​}'</script> where SaleshomeVF is the api name of the page, standard controller is User, thanks

Comment: got it, thanks! <script type="text/javascript">

window.top.location="the https stuff c.na12.visual.force.com/apex/MyVisualforcePage"

Comment: @jaw999 Glad I could be of service.